# JDBC using DataSource, DB2 and Kerberos

Tags: db2, db2-luw, java, jdbc, kerberos

I am trying to set up a JDBC using DataSource interface, DB2 database and Kerberos for authentication.
I am using IBMs documentation which refers in *Kerberos security with no user ID or password* [link here](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=sudsdjs-kerberos-security-under-data-server-driver-jdbc-sqlj#imjcc_cjvjcskb__title__3).

**Code block for DataSource**

```java
DB2SimpleDataSource dataSource = new DB2SimpleDataSource();
            dataSource.setDriverType(4);
            dataSource.setServerName("server");
            dataSource.setPortNumber(portnumber);
            dataSource.setDatabaseName("database name");
            dataSource.setSslConnection(true);
            dataSource.setClientProgramName("program name");
            dataSource.setRetrieveMessagesFromServerOnGetMessage(true);
            dataSource.setSecurityMechanism(dataSource.KERBEROS_SECURITY);
```

I have the following error in my console:

**Error message**

```
com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlException: [jcc][t4][10262][11223][4.19.49] Unexpected Throwable caught: class com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.le (in unnamed module @0x49097b5d) cannot access class sun.security.action.GetPropertyAction (in module java.base) because module java.base does not export sun.security.action to unnamed module @0x49097b5d. ERRORCODE=-4228, SQLSTATE=null
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.kd.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.kd.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.kd.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.b(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2SimpleDataSource.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2SimpleDataSource.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2SimpleDataSource.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at test.connection.TestDbConnectionDataSource.main(TestDbConnectionDataSource.java:81)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.le (in unnamed module @0x49097b5d) cannot access class sun.security.action.GetPropertyAction (in module java.base) because module java.base does not export sun.security.action to unnamed module @0x49097b5d
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.le.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.le.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.a(Unknown Source)
```

I am not using the `dataSource.setKerberosServerPrincipal("sample/srvlsj.ibm.com@SRVLSJ.SJ.IBM.COM");` which refers in IBM doc. Moreover, I am using many **realm** which I have to replace the `@SRVLSJ.SJ.IBM.COM`.
For this reason I am using the `System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.conf", "path\krb5.conf");`

The adove error I can resolve this error if I use in VM arguments this: `--add-exports java.base/sun.security.action=ALL-UNNAMED`. But, I am searching a way to still work without this in VM arguments.

Last details. I am using com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2SimpleDataSource interface. The version of DB2 is 4.19.49, jdk 17.0.6, Kerberos 5.

Comment: please edit your question (do not use comments) to add exact details of your KDC (name, version), and which jvm/jdk+version you are using, and what exactly do you mean by "I am using many realm".

Comment: How can I find the KDC in windows @mao?

Comment: Still unclear. Please learn how to be explicit when you edit your question  Do you mean that Microsoft Active-Directory is acting as your KDC? i.e. you are not using any third party product to act as the kerberos server?   Also, please clarify __whose__ jdk you are using, is it IBM, or Oracle, or OpenJDK. __details matter__  .